# session.modified False but Flask still sending set-cookie

Tags: flask, cookies, setcookie, response-headers, flask-session

I have the following configuration for flask:

```
app.config['SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST'] = False
app.config['SESSION_PERMANENT'] = True
```

I understood that since 'SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST' is False, it will not send set-cookie in the response when session is not modified.

In the after_request I check if session was modified:

```
@app.after_request
def add_header(response):
    if session.modified == False:
        print(response.headers)
    return response
```

It indeed wasn't!

No matter what I do, even when I explicit set session.modified = False, flask response have a set-cookie header with the session ID.

I need flask to not send set-cookie in the response because I want to connect my website with cloudflare, caching every response. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the behavior of sending set-cookies in http header, I modified the "should_set_cookie" function of session interface, right after you create you app instance:

```
from flask.sessions import SecureCookieSessionInterface, SessionMixin

class CustomSessionInterface(SecureCookieSessionInterface):
    def should_set_cookie(self, app: "Flask", session: SessionMixin) -> bool:
        if (session.modified == False and request.method == 'GET'):
            return False
        else:
            return True
        
app.session_interface = CustomSessionInterface()
```

This made sure it will not set-cookies if the session wasn't modified and is a GET request.

This is helping me a lot in cloud caching!

Comment: What does this actually change? If I understand correctly, ```should_get_cookie()``` returns ```False``` when ```app.config['SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST'] = False```